# Foundation for Apps, off canvas close on click off

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation for Apps, the angular version, and trying to use the off canvas menu. It works fine, opening and closing via setting links, but does not close when clicking off of it in the main content area like previous versions, and their example, do.

It's a really simple setup:

```
<zf-offcanvas id="menu" position="left">
<a zf-close="" class="close-button">×</a>

</zf-offcanvas>
<a zf-open="menu" class="button">Open Off-canvas</a>
```

And it should be done, but clicking anywhere on the main content (not the links) does not close the off canvas like their example docs:

http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/off-canvas

I'm looking for either a solution to this problem, or even a hacked out JS solution to close the window on clicking on "main" content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the "zf-close-all" attribute to the body tag.

```
<body zf-close-all>
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick. I'm surprised this isn't covered more in the docs, I'm pretty sure it was in their regular (non-app) docs.

Comment: You're welcome. The F6 apps doc is a bit patchy and not as exhaustive as the F6 sites doc.